# Using SQL CASE Statement how to find multiple items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a value for “THEN”  from   “Mortgage_Type” column if bellow conditions are true. Mortgage_Type and Category are same table and Equipment from another table. Tables are joining using Item_No. I need to find the Mortgage_Type of each item. I have 20+ Mortgage_Types if Category is main and Equipment is null then should display relevant Mortgage_Type

```
when SUM (Mortgage_Type)is not null and SUM (Equipment)is null and sum(Category) =’M’ THEN “value from Mortgage_Type column”
```

Comment: Please confirm, Contract is on Table1 and M_TYPE is on Table2?

Comment: Contract is on Table1 M_TYPE  is in table 1  Type is on table 2

Comment: Table schema with sample data

Comment: What do yo mean under "one contract can have one or more M_TYPEs"? M_TYPE ='V,M' ?

Comment: yes M_TYPE  can have V and M both then it should be display as Multiple

Comment: Can have both on one record, in same field as pers Hasan's example, or two records each with 'V' and 'M'?

Comment: no both are different field, one contract may have one or more fields

Comment: Ok, sorry - really need to echo Amit. Please show us the table schema.

Comment: you want like this ?
`select distinct Contract,
case
when CATOGORY not in ('M','O') and TYPE not in ('V','E') or M_TYPE ='V' or (M_TYPE  ='V' and M_TYPE ='M')  then 'VEHICLE'`

Comment: I think you have and/or mixed up or improperly precedenting each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this should help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Contract,
       CASE
          WHEN CATOGORY NOT IN ('M', 'O') AND TYPE NOT IN ('V', 'E')
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN M_TYPE = 'V' THEN 'VEHICLE'
                WHEN M_TYPE = 'O' THEN 'OTHERS'
                WHEN M_TYPE = 'M' THEN 'MORTGAGE'
                WHEN M_TYPE = 'H' THEN 'HOUSE'
                WHEN M_TYPE LIKE '%,%' THEN 'MULTIPLE'
             END
       END
          AS TYPE
  FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Contract = ID
```

Comment: WHEN M_TYPE LIKE '%,%' THEN 'MULTIPLE' this not help. M_TYPEs for the contract including different fields

Comment: Could you send example row for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cte and a window function. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  [Contract] int
  ,[M_TYPE] nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'V')
,(1, 'O')
,(1, 'M')
,(2, 'V')
,(3, 'V')
,(4, 'H')
,(4, 'V');

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT t.Contract,
         t.M_TYPE,
         COUNT(M_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Contract) Multi
    FROM @t t
)
SELECT DISTINCT [Contract], CASE
                              WHEN Multi > 1 THEN 'Multiple'
                              WHEN M_TYPE = 'V' THEN 'VEHICLE'
                              WHEN M_TYPE = 'O' THEN 'OTHERS'
                              WHEN M_TYPE = 'M' THEN 'MORTGAGE'
                              WHEN M_TYPE = 'H' THEN 'HOUSE'
                              ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
                            END AS MortgageType
  FROM cte
```